# Why does the theorem have inclusion if we already have equality

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-writing

The theorem is as follow:

"Let $G$ be a group and $N$ a subgroup of $G$. TFAE

- The subgroup is normal in $G$
- For all $g$ in $G$, $gNg^{-1}$ is a subgroup of $N$
- For all $g$ in $G$, $gNg^{-1}$ equals $N$

My question: What is the point of #2 if equality already holds in #3.

Comment: They're equivalent.  So, if you want to know that they are equal, (2) shows that you need only show one containment.

Comment: It basically says that in order to show that $gNg^{-1}=N$ it is enough to show that $gNg^{-1}\subseteq N$. (In some circumstances the other inclusion is not trivial and so this theorem is useful)

Comment: Ah I see! Thanks a lot